# Test Tornado Mongo RESTful web-service

Tags: unit-testing, mongodb, rest, tornado

I have an RESTful API which I developed using Tornado and mongo database.
I have tested my application manually using httppie.

Is there a way to test an API automatically?
I have looked up on to test tornado mongo application, but could not find any useful resource.

Could anyone please suggest me an approach which I can use to write my test to automatically test my API.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Tornado has inbuilt unit testing support. Use that? http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/testing.html

Answer (score 0):

RESTClient is a Java application to test RESTful webservices which has been in continuous development since 2007. It can be used to test variety of HTTP communications. There are two executables: GUI version; CLI version for batch execution of .rcq files

```
https://github.com/wiztools/rest-client
http://code.fosshub.com/WizToolsorg-RESTClient/downloads
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Tornado's `AsyncHTTPTestCase`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/testing.html#tornado.testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase):

```
class MyHTTPTest(tornado.testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase):

    def get_app(self):
        return my_app

    def test_get_foo(self):
        foo_url = self.get_url('/foo')
        response = self.http_client.fetch(foo_url)
        # test contents of response
        self.assertEqual(response.code, 200)

    def test_post_new_foo(self):
        foo_url = self.get_url('/foo')
        foo_obj = tornado.escape.json_encode({
            'an_object': 'blah blah'
            }
        request = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(foo_url,
            method='POST', body=foo_obj)
        # test contents of response
```

etc.